# Class does not confirm to Protocol CBPeripheralManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-bluetooth

I am new to IOS swift development, I am implementing a class PeripheralHandler in which i am initialising an instance of CBPeripheralManager. I have implemented the required delegate methods but still it showing error `'Type PeripheralHandler ->() -> PeripheralHandler!' does not confirm to CBPeripheralManagerDelegate.`

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class PeripheralHandler : NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{

    var myPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate:self, queue: nil)

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!)
    {
        println("peripheralManagerDidUpdateState called !!!")

        switch peripheral.state
        {
        case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOff:
            println("BLE OFF")
        case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn:
            println("BLE ON")
        case CBPeripheralManagerState.Unknown:
            println("NOT RECOGNIZED")
        case CBPeripheralManagerState.Unsupported:
            println("BLE NOT SUPPORTED")
        case CBPeripheralManagerState.Resetting:
            println("BLE NOT SUPPORTED")
        default:
            println("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a misleading error message. You can't reference `self` in the initial assignment of the instance variable. When instance variables are instantiated self doesn't necessarily contain anything meaningful, so Swift doesn't allow to use self.

You could use a lazy variable:

```
lazy var myPeripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager = {
    return CBPeripheralManager(delegate:self, queue: nil)
}()
```

This block will be called when you first access `myPeripheralManager`, and it will create the object for you.